# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, parse-platform, xcode5.1

I recently added the iOS Parse Framework to my Xcode 5 project. I am getting 10 errors now... None from code. They are all Apple Mach-O Linker Errors. I took the framework out and the errors went away. I am using the latest Parse.framework, so I do not know why I am getting these errors.

I also have another question, now that I updated to Xcode 5.1, when ever I use the UITabBarController or just want to add a tab bar to a ViewController... I gets all weird. The entire bar turns a solid grey...

Parse Mach-O Linker Error Picture
   http://postimg.org/image/s0y7b6a23/

UITabController Problem Picture
   http://postimg.org/image/osp4kdyej/

Comment: Nope.... :( It doesn't work that way...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Parse iOS quick start doc :

You need to have all these frameworks added to your build Target

[image]

Comment: **Do you know the answer to my second question?**

Comment: i have not updated to 5.1 , you should though post it as a separate question with proper title. other people might help

Comment: massive massive help

Answer (score 3):

I had similar linker errors using **v1.6.2** of the Parse SDK. except I got around 30 errors.

I ended up fixing the issue by removing the **`-ObjC`** linker flag from **`other linker flags`** under MyTarget > Build Settings > Linking.

[image: Other linker flags]

This is what the sample Parse project found in the *Quick Start* section of the Parse docs does, so let's assume that it's correct.

Comment: For **Cocoapods** : it took me forever to figure out how to use Parse with Cocoapods. The steps are these:
1. Remove ObjC linker flag like above __
2. Install CocoaPods using `pod intstall --no-integrate` __
3. [Drag the generated pods project into xcode as a subproject](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode). __
4. Follow steps in link except for creating a new target, linking binary with library, and adding the -ObjC flag __

Tag me in comments if you run into problems, I'll try to help.

Comment: But I have a issue when using this with Google Map Kit, because it is necessary to set -ObjC flag for that. Do you have any idea to deal in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete path under target->Build Settings->Library Search Paths for your first question.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution step by step for fixing this problem (it is useless to modify your Xcode project's configuration, you just have to use the latest versions of all softwares, API(s), tools + clean all XCode builds and everything will be alright):**

1 - Use the latest versions of Xcode, Swift/Objective-C and iOS.

2 - Delete all Xcode builds.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

3 - Install/Update Cocoapods (it is important to use the last version) to manage dependencies.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

4 - Update your Podfile:

```
vim Podfile

pod '[Name of the API]', '>= [Any API version]'
```

5 - Update your local repository:

```
pod repo update
```

6 - Update the dependencies of the Xcode project:

```
pod update
```

Generally from that point your "Apple Mach-O Linker Error Parse" will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To your second question - I had images that were not sized correctly in my tab bar and got the same result you speak of. I deleted them out of the tab bar and it went back to normal. Not sure if this answers your question, but doing this solved the problem for me. Tab bar images should be 50x50.

Answer (score 0):

Ok its July 2015 and I tried all the solutions above but finally resolved this by using adding Parse through CocoaPods and removing (or not adding in the first place) the frameworks directly in my project.