# Xcode 5 Parse Framework Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, linker, parse-platform

When calling `[Parse setApplicationId: clientKey:]` from the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in AppDelegate.m, I receive the following error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have included all frameworks necessary for Parse as stated in [Apple Mach-O Linker Error Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509290/apple-mach-o-linker-error-parse). I have `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` at the top of AppDelegate.m. I have cleaned the build several times. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check all frameworks in "Link Binary With Libraries" in project's build-phase tab.

Comment: For some reason `Parse.framework` was not in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section even though it was in both my `Frameworks` folder and the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section in the project's general tab. After dragging `Parse.framework` to "Link Binary With Libraries", the errors disappeared. Thank you!