# many errors when updating parse sdk

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I updated to Parse SDK 1.6.1 by deleting the Parse and ParseFacebookUtils frameworks and adding back those two and the Bolts framework. This resulted in some 53 errors. I then ensured I had linked all the libraries indicated in the accepted answer here: [Apple Mach-O Linker Error Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509290/apple-mach-o-linker-error-parse) and that got me down to about 30 errors, but that's doesn't quite cut it. Here's a screenshot of the kind of errors I'm getting:

[image]

What's going on? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this release you also need to add the `libstdc++.6.dylib` library.

The current Parse Starter Project has the following :

[image]

Comment: The doc is out of date, but it has been reported here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/311780442362985/

Comment: Thanks. Sure would be nice if Parse maintained their much-linked-to Quick Start Guide.

Comment: All of these dependencies have always been listed in the Quick Start, which is linked from our docs: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/crashreporting/ios/existing

Comment: Thanks for this tip!! I didnt see this anywhere on the Parse webpage