# Cocoapods with Parse architecture issue

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, cocoapods

I have a project in which I added Parse manually (added source code manually, linked frameworks etc.). Now, trying to add cocoapods to the project breaks it horribly. I get around 50 build time errors. They are all mach-o linker errors. The reason I believe that it's linked to parse is because I get linker errors like the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
  -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
```

These continue throughout the rest of the error log, and end with this:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is what my `Podfile` looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'The Underground' do
pod 'IDMPhotoBrowser'
end

target 'The UndergroundTests' do

end
```

I would love to work with someone to try and diagnose this problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: What version of Parse are you using ? (PFTwitterUtils are a separate framework now).

Comment: You probably forgot to link the Accounts framework. Also why not add Parse using cocoa pods too ? just add pod 'Parse' and pod 'ParseTwitterUtils' to your podfile

Comment: I added the Accounts framework and I still get 48 errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well maybe there are other frameworks missing. Can you add the entire error output ? Also have you tried to add Parse using cocoa pods ? It's much simpler, cocoapods is a great tool !

Comment: I agree, but it's already implemented manually so I think for now I'll keep it. I will include the full output in a different comment

Comment: Here is the output: https://gist.github.com/mcdappdev/34e9d748508ed5d8e66a

Comment: You're still missing at least the Facebook iOS SDK (it's here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios), the libstdc++.6.dylib and the Social framework (System stuff, add it through Xcode)

Comment: See this question, it might help as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776021/many-errors-when-updating-parse-sdk

Comment: Even if I'm not using any facebook functionality I still need this? Everything was working totally fine until I tried adding pods

Comment: Don't add ParseFacebookUtils if you don't need Facebook support

Comment: Also adding ParseFacebookUtils and ParseFacebookUtilsV4 is a mistake, they are 2 versions of the same framework.

Comment: Down to one error!! :) Here is the error log: https://gist.github.com/mcdappdev/a55842a54560411732ac

Comment: Did you add SDWebImage manually ? It's added by cocoapods now, so you have it twice. Remove your manual install (one more reason to go cocoa pods all the way once you start, otherwise you're going to have this kind of problem very often...).

Comment: Ah, yes I bet that's the problem. Let me check

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you so much :)