# iOS Mach-o linker error parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linker-errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke226 in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke319 in Parse(PFObject.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFileManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFInstallation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPin.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSession.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyPin.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFileManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFInstallation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPin.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEncoder.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am getting this error

I used below link as reference and I implemented all framework from that

[Apple Mach-O Linker Error Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509290/apple-mach-o-linker-error-parse)

My code is in Swift and I can not able to find that how to solve that error.

Anyone can reply for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ways:

**1)** if you use also use the Facebook SDK look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920666/parse-and-facebook-sdk-bolts-framework-error). The solution seems to be:

> Add to your AppDelegate.m or another class following constant after
>   imports and before implementation section:  NSString *const
>   BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";

**2)** check your **Library Search Paths Flag**, maybe you have old reference no more present in your project.

**3)** remove the -ObjC flag in **Other Linker Flags** on **Build Settings**.